# bootstrap custom radio button toggle hidden input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a custom radio button snippet from bootsnipp and in the description on the page it says the value can be toggled using the hidden input but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Could someone shed some light on this?
Lets say I want the second group to only show up if the first option in the first group is selected, using jQuery.

```js
$('.radioBtn a').on('click', function(){
     var sel = $(this).data('title');
     var tog = $(this).data('toggle');
     $('#'+tog).prop('value', sel);
     
     $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"]').not('[data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
     $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"][data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.radioBtn .notActive{
     color: #3276b1;
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="radioBtn btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="option-set-one" data-title="option-one">Option 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="option-set-one" data-title="option-two">Option 2</a>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="option-set-one" id="option-set-one">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="radioBtn btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="option-set-two" data-title="option-three">Option 3</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="option-set-two" data-title="option-four">Option 4</a>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="option-set-two" id="option-set-two">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have two div#radioBtn on the same page. ID's are meant to be unique. As per your question, you don't need a hidden input if you're using jQuery, in your click callback function use a simple `if` to decide whether or not to display the second group.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that and changed it to classes. If I were to put these buttons in a form, how do I check which one of the two in that group is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like this:

```
if($('a[data-title="option-one"]').hasClass('active'))
    alert('option one is active');
else
    alert('option one is inactive');
```

Also note the change I made to your markup, you can't have two `class` attributes on the same element. If you want two different classes on the same element write it like so: `class="myClass1 myClass2"`

To check it in PHP you'll have to use a hidden input, use the `if` is just gave you to change the value of the input before submitting:

```
if($('a[data-title="option-one"]').hasClass('active'))
        $('input[name="myHiddenInput"]').val(1);
    else
        $('input[name="myHiddenInput"]').val(0);
```

Then in your PHP code (assuming POST) use:

```
if($_POST['myHiddenInput'] == '1') ....
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if you could help me with another part too, do you know how I would check it in php?